# Showing $\frac{k + a}{k + b} > \frac{a}{b}$ with $a > b$ and $a, b, k \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Tags: inequality

Given the 2 terms
$$ \frac{k + a}{k + b}$$
and $$\frac{a}{b}$$
with $a, b, k \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $a > b$

I want to show, that the first term is always bigger than the second one.

**My try**
$$
  \frac{k + a}{k + b}  > \frac{a}{b} \\
  \frac{k + b + (a - b)}{k + b} > \frac{b + (a - b)}{b} \\
  1 + \frac{a - b}{k + b}> 1 + \frac{a - b}{b} \\
  \frac{1}{k + b} > \frac{1}{b} \\
  k + b > b
$$
the problem is, that I think the inequality sign has to change to $<$ in the last step because of calculating the inverse on both sides. That would mean
$$ k + b < b$$
which is nonsense.

Comment: I don't think your assertion is true. For example, take $a=2,b=1,k=1$. Then you would say "$\frac32>21$", which is clearly false. In fact, the fraction decreases to $1$ as $k$ increases. So the very opposite is true, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you're trying to prove the *wrong* inequality: what's true is that
$$
\frac{k+a}{k+b}<\frac{a}{b}
$$

Since all terms are positive, the inequality is equivalent to
$$
b(k+a)<a(k+b)
$$
that is
$$
bk<ak
$$
that's true.

You can also go backwards:
\begin{gather}
b<a\\
bk<ak\\
bk+ab<ak+ab\\
b(k+a)<a(k+b)\\
\frac{b(k+a)}{b(k+b)}<\frac{a(k+b)}{b(k+b)}\\
\frac{k+a}{k+b}<\frac{a}{b}
\end{gather}

---

You could do in a different way:
\begin{gather}
\frac{k+a}{k+b}=\frac{k+a}{k+b}-\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{b}
=\frac{kb+ab-ka-kb}{b(k+b)}+\frac{a}{b}=\frac{k(a-b)}{b(k+b)}+\frac{a}{b}
\end{gather}

Comment: @user236182 Yes, I went to the correct one without even noticing!

Answer (score 0):

You have :

$$
a > b 
$$

and  $$
k > 0$$
then

$$ ak > bk$$
then
$$ak+ab >bk+ab$$
then
$$a(k+b) >b(k+a)$$

Answer (score 0):

It's true that $\frac{k+a}{k+b}<\frac{a}{b}$ for all $a,b,k\in\mathbb R^+, a>b$ (i.e. the opposite of the original claim is true). Proof (I'm copying your solution with some changes):

$$\frac{k + a}{k + b}  < \frac{a}{b} \\
  \iff \frac{k + b + (a - b)}{k + b} < \frac{b + (a - b)}{b} \\
  \iff 1 + \frac{a - b}{k + b}< 1 + \frac{a - b}{b} \\
  \iff \frac{1}{k + b} < \frac{1}{b} \\
  \iff k + b > b\iff k>0,$$

which is true. But the better approach here is to simply multiply both sides by $(k+b)b$ (all the terms are positive, so we can do that without changing $<$,$>$) to get:

$$\iff b(k+a)<a(k+b)\iff bk<ak,$$

which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $a$ apples and $b$ bananas, with more apples than bananas.  If someone gives you $k$ more of each fruit, the new ratio of apples to bananas is less than the old ratio (since the new fruit came in at a ratio of $1:1$ which is less than $a:b$).

So $\frac{a+k}{b+k}<\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Say there are $b$ ounces of pure alcohol in $a$ ounces of solution, so the concentration is $\frac{b}{a}$ ( $< 1$). Adding  $k$ ounces of pure alcohol will increase the concentration to $\frac{ k+b} {k+a}$ .

Answer (score 0):

*With the basic rules on inequalities:*
The general fact is this:

> Suppose $a, b, k>0$. Then:
>
> - If $\dfrac ab >1$, then $\;\dfrac ab >\dfrac{a+k}{b+k}> 1$;
> - If $\dfrac ab <1$, then $\;\dfrac ab <\dfrac{a+k}{b+k}< 1$.

Indeed the first upper inequality is equivalent to
$$\dfrac ab >\dfrac{a+k}{b+k}\iff a(b+k)>b(a+k)\iff ak>bk\iff a>b. $$
The second upper inequality results from $a>b\implies a+k>b+k$.

The lower inequalities come down to the upper ones taking reciprocals.